# I want to make plugin for Woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I would like to make wordpress plugin with woocommerce. My idea was making something like crowdfunding (displaying earned money, target money etc.). I made a script that gets the ID of product but when I try to use wc_get_product($id) i get errors "Call to undefined function wc_get_product()". I tried including woocommerce.php file but then I got "wc_get_product should not be called before the woocommerce_init, woocommerce_after_register_taxonomy
and woocommerce_after_register_post_type actions have finished."

Main file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: xxx
 * Plugin URI: xxx
 * Description: xxx
 * Version: xxx
 * Author: xxx.com
 * Author URI: xxx
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'Plugin file cannot be accessed directly.' );
/* prevents submit button from sendind the same data twice (off for now)
function preventResubmit(){
    ?>
<script>
    if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
        window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
    }
</script>
<?php
}
*/

require(dirname(__FILE__).'/shortcodes.php');

add_action("admin_menu","cfdg_add_admin_menu");

function cfdg_add_admin_menu(){
    add_menu_page("Crowdfunding","Crowdfunding", "manage_options", "cfdg-admin", "cfdg_add_page", "dashicons-money");
}
function cfdg_add_page(){
    require (dirname(__FILE__).'/adminmenu.php');
}

?>
```

shortcodes.php

```
<?php

$earnedMoney = cfdg_getEarnedMoney();
$targetMoney = 30000;


function cfdg_getEarnedMoney() {
    global $wpdb;
    
    $cdfg_money_to_return = 0;
    $sql = 'SELECT ml.product_id FROM wp_wc_order_product_lookup AS pl 
    JOIN wp_wc_product_meta_lookup AS ml ON pl.product_id = ml.product_id
    JOIN wp_posts AS wp ON wp.ID = pl.order_id WHERE LOCATE("crowdfunding",sku) AND (wp.post_status = "wc-processing" OR wp.post_status = "wc-completed");';
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    if(!$results) return 0;

    foreach($results as $res){
        $cdfg_produkcik = wc_get_product($res); /* <--- HERE I GET THE ERROR */
        $cdfg_product_price= $cdfg_produkcik->get_price();
        $cdfg_money_to_return += $cdfg_product_price;
    }
        return $cdfg_money_to_return ;
}



//PROGRESS BAR
add_shortcode('cfdg_progress_bar', 'cfdg_func_progress_bar');

function cfdg_func_progress_bar(){
    global $earnedMoney; global $targetMoney;

    echo "Earned: ".$earnedMoney." from: ".$targetMoney." required";
}
//END OF PROGRESS BAR



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the global WooCommerce variable.

```
global $woocommerce;
//make sure that woocommerce plugin is active
```

Comment: I made changes. Added:
```
include_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');

global $woocommerce;
add_action( 'admin_init', 'check_some_other_plugin' );

function check_some_other_plugin(){
    if(is_plugin_active( "woocommerce/woocommerce.php"))
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/shortcodes.php');
    else echo "Inactive";
}
``` 
to main file. Now my shortcode is not loading as if shortcodes.php is not loaded (which might be the case)

Comment: Worth to mention is that those functions doesn't work in my plugin but using XYZ PHP Code Snippet it loads just fine.

Comment: Okay, great , cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
require_once(../../wp-load.php)
```

Comment: I tried require_once(ABSPATH."wp-load.php"); but it didn't work :/

Comment: Maybe the path to your wp-load.php is not correct please re-check it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of commenting or asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."